# Function chaining with different return values?

Tags: php, function, return-value, chaining

Is it possible to have a method return different values depending on context (how the return value is used)? For example, could a method return `$this` when it's then used with the arrow operator to call another method (i.e. chaining method calls), but return a scalar when the return value isn't used this way?

Case 1:

```
$result = $test->doSomething1(); // returns 4
// $result returns 4
```

Case 2:

```
$result = $test->doSomething1()->doSomething2();
// doSomething1() returns $this
// doSomething2() returns 8
```

Is there anyway to perform such a behaviour?

Comment: Why "$test->doSomething1()" return `4` (case 1) and `$this` (case 2)?

Comment: What you really want to do is not possible, now I'm wondering, do you really want this, or have you mistyped the question?

Comment: @GabrielSantos Yes I want this, it would have been a lot easier than storing the value and pulling that after my chained functions.

Comment: I think your comment is one of correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want a method (`doSomething1`) to return a value based on what the rest of the call chain looks like. Unfortunately, there is absolutely no way you can do this.

Common programming paradigms shared across "all" languages (how methods, operators and such work in the context of the grammar) dictate that the result of the expression `$this->doSomething1()` has to be worked out before the result of possibly calling `->doSomething2()` on it can be considered. Statically typed and dynamically typed languages do this in different ways, but the common factor is that the expression `$this->doSomething1()` has to be considered independently of what follows or does not follow.

In a nutshell: `$this->doSomething1()` has to return a specific type of value in both cases. And in PHP there is no way to have a type of value that can behave like a number in one context and like an object with methods to call in another.

Comment: +1. As to your remark about "all" languages: I think Python might be willing to accept this kind of syntax, but I'm not sure, as I don't use it all that often. Any Python experts in the room?

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible to have a function return different values depending on if another function is called on the returned value or not. You can emulate this with toString() (where conversion to string is applicable, or another function that you call at the end of every chain to get the value instead of the object:

```
$test = new foo();
echo $test->doSomething1(); // Outputs 1

$test = new foo();
echo $test->doSomething1()->doSomething2(); // Outputs 3

$test = new foo();
$result = $test->doSomething1()->done(); // $result === 1

$test = new foo();
$result = $test->doSomething1()->doSomething2()->done(); // $result === 3

class foo {

    private $val;

    function __construct($val = 0){
        $this->val = $val;
    }

    function doSomething1(){
        $this->val += 1;
        return $this;
    }

    function doSomething2(){
        $this->val += 2;
        return $this;
    }

    function done(){
        return $this->val;
    }

    function __toString(){
        return (string)$this->val;
    }

}
```

[**Codepad Example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8VzhMY)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186210/825789) suggests creating an internal call stack on the class, so you can keep track of where you are on the method chain. This could be used to return `$this` or something else, depending on the context.

Comment: No, it could not be used to return `$this` or something else. That answer implicitly *always* returns `$this`.

Comment: @Jon, I was thinking of using that call stack array suggested on that answer to decide what to return. Looking back now, I realized that's not possible, because the information required for that decision will only be available after the method already return (when the second, chained method is called).